# Segmentation fault 11 when trying to sort array by passing it to a function by address

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size);  
void sort (int* arr[], int size);

int main(void){
    int initialArray[] = {540, 2100, 5150, 3};
    int size = sizeof(initialArray) / sizeof(initialArray[0]); //get length of array
    int copiedArray[size]; //make new array at size of initial array

    arrayCopy(&initialArray, &copiedArray, size); //copy 

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("initialArray, %d: %d -> copiedArray, %d: %d\n", i, initialArray[i], i,  copiedArray[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    sort(&copiedArray, size);

    printf("Sorted array: {");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d,", copiedArray[i]);
    }

    printf("}\n");

    return 0;
}

/*

copies all the elements from one array to another

*/

void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *toArray[i] = *fromArray[i];
    }
}

/*

sorts a given array in ascending order

*/

void sort(int* arr[], int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        if(*arr[i] < *arr[i + 1]){
            int temp = *arr[i + 1];
            *arr[i + 1] = *arr[i];
            *arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple application to learn pass by address/reference in C. I created a function to copy the contents of 1 array to another. The second function is to sort the newly created array. When I try to run this, it gives me a segmentation fault error and the following warnings after compiling:

```
proj1.c:12:12: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[4]' to parameter of type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    arrayCopy(&initialArray, &copiedArray, size); //copy 
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
proj1.c:4:21: note: passing argument to parameter 'fromArray' here
void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size);
                ^
proj1.c:12:27: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[size]' to parameter of type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    arrayCopy(&initialArray, &copiedArray, size); //copy 
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
proj1.c:4:39: note: passing argument to parameter 'toArray' here
void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size);
                                  ^
proj1.c:20:7: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[size]' to parameter of type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    sort(&copiedArray, size);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
proj1.c:5:17: note: passing argument to parameter 'arr' here
void sort (int* arr[], int size);
            ^
3 warnings generated.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size);`  -> `void arrayCopy(int fromArray[], int toArray[], int size);  `

Comment: and modify definition accordingly. similarly with `sort()` function

Answer (score 0):

According to your `arrayCopy()` declaration compiler will consider 1st argument as double pointer `*fromArray` will have address of `initialArray` and `**fromArray` will contain `540` and in function definition you are trying to deference `540` address which is invalid so change `void arrayCopy(int* fromArray[], int* toArray[], int size);` -> `void arrayCopy(int fromArray[], int toArray[], int size);` and check following modified program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void arrayCopy(int fromArray[], int toArray[], int size);  
void sort (int arr[], int size);

int main(void){
    int initialArray[] = {540, 2100, 5150, 3};
    int size = sizeof(initialArray) / sizeof(initialArray[0]); //get length of array
    int copiedArray[size]; //make new array at size of initial array
    int i;

    arrayCopy(initialArray, copiedArray, size); //copy 

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("initialArray, %d: %d -> copiedArray, %d: %d\n", i, initialArray[i], i,  copiedArray[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    sort(copiedArray, size);

    printf("Sorted array: {");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d,", copiedArray[i]);
    }

    printf("}\n");

    return 0;
}

/*

copies all the elements from one array to another

*/

void arrayCopy(int fromArray[], int toArray[], int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        toArray[i] = fromArray[i];
    }
}

/*

sorts a given array in ascending order

*/

void sort(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        if(arr[i] < arr[i + 1]){
            int temp = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&initialArray` is a pointer with type `int (*)[4]` . This is not compatible with `int **` which you have declared your function to take.

The simplest solution is to have your function take `int *`, being a pointer to the first element of the array. For example:

```
void arrayCopy(int const *from, int *to, size_t num_ints)
{
     memcpy(to, from, num_ints * sizeof(int));
}
```

and you call it like:

```
arrayCopy( initialArray,  copiedArray, size );
```

Writing `initialArray` in this context is the same as writing `&initialArray[0]` ; so the function has a pointer to the first array element and also the count of array elements, so the function has all the information it needs.

Answer (score -1):

1. You generally can't allocate arrays like that (`int copiedArray[size];`). The compiler allows that because the size is known at compile time. If you don't hardcode the initialArray (e.g. you want user to fill at runtime), than the program won't compile. In this case, use `malloc` (not `new[]`, since you are writing in C, not C++).
2. Pointers. Use them right.

   ```
   void arrayCopy(int fromArray[], int toArray[], int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
           toArray[i] = fromArray[i];
   }
   ...
   arrayCopy(initialArray, copiedArray, size);
   ```
3. Your sort functions lacks one nested loop. Google *bubble sort*.

Comment: Standard C99 allows static arrays with variable size. It is completely OK.

Comment: @AlexLop, if you declare both arrays with a constant expresion you don't need to use C99 issues and your code is portable to pre C99 compilers.  As you are initializing the first with a constant array, you can use the size of that array as the constant expression you need in the second declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the definition:

```
int arr[N];
```

`arr` is already a pointer to that array and equivalent to `&arr[0]` so using `&arr` is just undefined in this case (address of the address of the first element... there is no such thing).

Since `arr` is already a pointer to the array in the memory, all that is needed to do, in order to modify that array inside a function, is just to pass `arr` and the size of the array:

```
void my_func(int array_to_sort[], int array_size);
```

and then you can call that function like this:

```
my_func(arr, N);
```

Comment: I'm afraid not.  `arr` by definition, is a pointer reference to the first element of the array, and as such in this case, is of type `int *`.  `&arr` is (also by definition) the address of the array, and, as such is of type `int (*)[N]` (pointer to an array of N elements).  You can check that both pointers point to the same address, and that they are different types, if you try to print `sizeof *arr` and `sizeof *&arr`.

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks Luis. I learned something new. Actually I never used &arr since I had no reason to do so. But now I see that I had a wrong understanding of such representation.